# Error accessing a nested JSON using boost::json?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-json

Using the following json:

```
{
    type: "test",
    version: 1,
    data: {
        name: "omni",
        id: "123",
        value: 3
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get its data using 2 C++ functions:

```
void process_data(std::string type, std::string data)
{
        boost::json::value data = boost::json::parse(data);
        std::string name = json.at("name").as_string().c_str();
        std::string id = json.at("id").as_string().c_str();
        int value = json.at("value").as_int64();

        std::cout << "Message data content:" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Name: " << name << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Id: " << id << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Value: " << value << std::endl;
}

void process_message(std::string payload)
{
        boost::json::value json = boost::json::parse(payload);
        std::string type = json.at("type").as_string().c_str();
        int version = json.at("version").as_int64();

        std::cout << "Message received:" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Type: " << type << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Version: " << version << std::endl;

        std::string data = json.at("data").as_string().c_str(); !!! Getting error here
        process_data(data);
}
```

I'm getting the following error when parsing `data`:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::wrapexcept<std::invalid_argument>'
  what():  not a string
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: `json.at("data")` is not a string. It's an object.

Comment: yes, I know... my idea was to convert to string and pass it down to the second function... if not, how to do it?

Comment: Why would you do this? Why do you want to parse this object twice? Pass a parsed JSON object. If you want to pass a string, you have to [serialize](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/json/doc/html/json/ref/boost__json__serialize.html) the object. Why do you return a string, convert it to a C string to immediately convert it back to a string with `as_string().c_str()`? Why do you flush the buffer after each line with `std::endl`? Why do you copy the string for each function call? You should post it a [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) after you fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can not treat a JSON object as if it is a string. As the commenter says, serialize it instead:

```
std::string data = serialize(json.at("data"));
```

However serializing is an anti-pattern unless you are going to send over (text) protocol. Instead, pass the json value:

```
process_data(json.at(“data”));
```

The best part is that it will include the type if it’s variant.

Comment: thanks for your post, but.... hum... that's not exactly what I need. I need as to pass over to process_data as std::string... modules and api's issues on my architecture...

Comment: Did you… read the first sentence? That _is_ exactly what you need then. The second half was hypothesizing based on the code shown. If that’s not the case, just use the first line of code.